# How to Merge two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, django, merge

I would like to merge two dictionaries this way below:

```
dict1={
     'kl':'ngt',
     'schemas':
            [
              {
               'date':'14-12-2022',
               'name':'kolo'
              }
           ]
     }
  
 dict2={
     'kl':'mlk',
     'schemas':
            [
              {
               'date':'14-12-2022',
               'name':'maka'
              }
           ],
   
     }
```

then I create a variable that will group the two dictionaries in this way

```
all_dict=[
    'kl':'ngt',
    'schemas':
        [
          {
           'date':'14-12-2022',
           'name':'kolo'
          }
       ],
     
     'kl':'mlk',
     'schemas':
           [
             {
               'date':'23-10-2022',
               'name':'maka'
          }
       ]
   ......
 ]
```

How to get this result. I'm stuck right now please help me if possible

Comment: Your target structure is invalid, so what you want is not possible. The keys in a  dictionary have to be unique, you can't repeat the `schemas` key like that.

Comment: Try to write out the target structure by hand for just two dicts, until you get a structure you are happy with. Then post that as a question if you still have difficulty making it from your individual dicts in code.

Comment: and if i wanted for example to get this target structure all_dict=[{..},{...} ]

Comment: you can use asterisk mark for merge them but attention duplication keys , it'll put last key/value , `{**dict1,**dict2}`

Comment: @PathiaNanto if your target structure is all_dict=[{...},{...}] then you just need to do all_dict=[dict1,dict2]

Comment: and `[{...},{...}]` is a **list** of dicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the result structure that you want is like this:

```
all_dict=[
{
    'kl':'ngt',
    'schemas':
        [
          {
           'date':'14-12-2022',
           'name':'kolo'
          }
       ],
},

     {

     'kl':'mlk',
     'schemas':
           [
             {
               'date':'23-10-2022',
               'name':'maka'
          }
       ]
}
   ......
 ]
```

so to get this result should only do this:

```
all_dict = [dict1, dict2]
```

or

```
all_dict = []
all_dict.append(dict1)
all_dict.append(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is a dictionary with two keys with the same string "schemas". That's not possible.

Comment: I modified the target structure, how to get that??